# Accessing ConcurrentDictionary in destructor

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I have a `Wrapper<T> where T : class` that wraps around my objects. I store `WeakReference<Wrapper<T>>` in a `ConcurrentDictionary`, to implement weakly-referenced thread-safe cache for immutable objects that gets automatically cleaned up when memory is required for something else. I need to call `ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove` in the `Wrapper` destructor to free the weak references in the dictionary that no longer point to a valid object.

It is well-known that we should not use any locking inside destructors because of the risk of dead-lock. So I wonder, can I use `ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove` safely in a destructor? I am afraid it might have been implemented using `SpinLock` or some other tool and thus still presents a risk of dead-lock when used in destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the implementation of the ConcurrentDictionary at this [location](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,2e5ef5704344a309) and the TryRemove implementation uses 'lock(...)'.

What you could do inside the destructor is use the thread pool to perform the removal of the item from the dictionary. You would still need to mark the wrapper instance as no longer valid, so that if a call is made to any of its public methods between the finalizer running and the thread pool removing it, you could detect this and reject the call.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Could you please suggest some work-around? One could be to use `Interlocked` to set a flag that the collection needs to be purged and then `CompareExchange` for the flag in each public method, but that's not very clean solution. Can I use some silliness like starting a thread in destructor that would clean-up the collection after GC is completed? I am not sure whether threads started from destructor are in suspended state until GC is done or whether they run concurrently.

Comment: Update with suggestion on using the thread pool for removing the item.

Comment: So if I schedule a task on thread-pool (`Task.Factory.StartNew`, or others except for `new Thread()`), then the thread will start ONLY AFTER all the garbage collection is finished? I am worried that by starting any type of thread in finalizer, the thread might run concurrently with the finalizing thread. And maybe it happens that the dictionary is getting garbage collected too while I'm in the `Wrapper` finalizer, so starting a new thread to do cleanup on a collection that is just being collected might be a bad idea.

Comment: I don't know if the garbage collector stops all other managed threads whilst it is running.

Comment: Well I just did some experimentation and if you start a thread in finalizer, it runs concurrently with the finalizer thread.

Comment: Your thread pool suggestion is complete overkill and unnecessary. Finalizers do not run on the GC thread, they run on the finalizer thread which runs concurrently with your application and concurrent dictionary operations are very fast and block for only a very short period of time. General locking is discouraged in finalizers because a poorly written one will deadlock the finalizer thread but in this case it shouldn't be an issue and it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you **DON'T** want to use locking in a destructor is due to the fact that the destructor might be called by a FinalizerWorker in a sperate thread while stopping execution on all threads.

Thus, if one thread is in the middle of a ConcurrencyDicitonary operation when the FinalizerWorker is kicked off you might deadlock if the destructor tries to lock the ConcurrencyDictionary (this can be a very difficult to reproduce deadlock).

A spin lock wont help you because if ANY currently executing thread has the ConcurrencyDictionary locked or the Spinner variable locked it **WILL NOT** release it until the FinalizerWorker completes, which it wont because it will spin/lock forever.

You'r main options here is to implement the IDisposable interface with a SuppressFinalize(this) call, since your object will suppress the Finalizer worker no deadlock can occure and ConcurrencyDictionary operations ARE SAFE !

Thus if you pre-empt Finalizer using object.Dispose() you should be safe use ConcurrencyDictionary, but otherwise **DO NOT** use any types of locks in your Finalizer Dispose(false) call or you will deadlock at some point.

```
// Design pattern for a base class.
public class Base: IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;
//Implement IDisposable.
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        //Disposing outside the FinalizerWorker (SAFE)
        if (disposing)            
            m_pDictionary.TryRemove(this);            

        disposed = true;
    }
}

// Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code.
~Base()
{
    // Simply call Dispose(false).
    Dispose (false);
}
```

Comment: Read the question, question is `can I use ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove safely in a destructor?`.

Comment: Why even try if it can throw an exception which are a no no in the destructor. Its generally bad for to clean outside resources in the destructor. IDisposable is there for a reason

Comment: @GaryKaizer And you realize that the MSDN's recommended `IDisposable` implementation pattern calls `Dispose` in the destructor right?

Comment: You are right, I am a little too used to managed C++ where there is a difference, will amend my code to only include I disposable with a check for bDisposing.

Comment: Fixed my answer with a full explanation of why to use idisposable cross threading deadlock. I apologize for my lackluster earlier answer without proper reasoning.

Comment: @GaryKaizer Well thanks for the write-up but I am well-aware of the issues of locking in destructor. Spinlock was not mentioned as a solution but as a threat. Under no circumstances can I get rid of the destructor. What I really need is to find a way to invoke `ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove` somehow, and this invocation needs to be signaled/started from destructor. Using flags and wrapping all my public methods to check for signal is obvious solution, but I am looking for something that can do the clean-up regardless of whether any further public method calls will be made on my class.

Comment: You might be in a pickle then because cleaning up resources that the object doesn't own from inside the finalizer is a tough issue if you can't suppress the object from being put on the finalizer thread. You'r main option at this point is to create your own seperate thread for the WeakReference objects that are ready to be disposed and keep them in a seperate container and whenever memory is needed lock your collection and do a manual dispose on them.... pretty much re-implementing the garbage collector, but in a thread safe manner.

Comment: So how would you safely notify that separate thread from the finalizer to add the current instance to clean-up queue? I can hardly use collections because they suffer from the same locking issue if I want to make them thread-safe. Maybe I could implement my own linked list somehow using `Interlocked` to make it safe. But then my concerns with using dedicated thread mentioned in `Phil Wright`'s answer apply. Not to mention that the thread could prevent the entire collection from being garbage collected.

Comment: I would set static volatile List and add the object to the delete list and then trigger a static Event to let the cleanup thread know that there are objects in the delete list. When the normal execution pattern resumes the thread will proceed and global lock your Wrapper, cleaning up all your immutable objects, and sync your ConcurrencyList then unlock your Wrapper and wait for the next cleanup.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention since you know only two threads will be using your delete list you can safly manipulate a non threadsafe list since it will be locked during the finalizer (since the delete thread is suspended) and the list only gets appended to. Just make sure to use an indexed for loop in your delete thread instead of an enumerated foreach.

Comment: But if you trigger static event from the finalizer, then you end up waking the thread before the GC is complete. I need a way to schedule thread execution after GC is finished. And I think that using generic list is not thread-safe despite the fact that delete thread is suspended - he could got suspended in the middle of removing items from the list.

Comment: Add a GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); as the first statement after a signal .

Comment: I think you're mixing here two different things:
  a) FinalizerWorker thread;
  b) Garbage Collector thread.

Where FinalizerWorker is not very different from any other thread, while GC thread potentially "stops the world", thus locking techniques can lead there to dead lock. Fortunately, you cannot implement any logic in GC thread, as it's completely implemented by the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The answers on here are leading you astray. Using locks in a destructor/finalizer is discouraged because it can easily lead to deadlocks, especially when implemented "manually" instead of using a concurrent collection, but sometimes it is necessary. Even on "stop the world" GC implementations finalizers run on a separate finalizer thread that chugs along concurrently with your application.

First thing is first though - it is VERY RARE that what you are suggesting is the ideal way of implementing your desired functionality, to the point where I am quite confident it isn't. To start, WeakReferences are not suitable for use in caching because they get collected far more often than just when "memory is needed". A proper cache implementation monitors memory levels with strong references and releases them as needed when memory usage is too high.

Even in implementations like a WeakValueDictionary where you don't want the collection holding onto the value if it can be collected, the implementation still doesn't receive object collection notifications. Instead you just remove the entry whenever you stumble upon one that was collected, or you scan the entire collection for dead entries every X operations, or every Y seconds, etc.

That said, if you do run into a situation where you NEED to do something when an object is collected, you can use concurrent collections just fine.

Assuming you don't do anything silly, queuing up an ID in a notification queue or removing an item from a concurrent dictionary is safe because those operations are fast and block for only a very short period of time and your application is not blocked while your finalizers run.

It's something you should avoid as much as possible, but sometimes it's the best and only way to implement something. Just make sure that the lock is fast and used as minimally as possible, and not part of any multi-level locking schemes that are easy to accidentally get wrong and deadlock.